# Why would Resharper enter "foo foo" whenever I hit "Enter" from within a script tag

Tags: sencha-touch, resharper

I am currently using ReSharper build 6.0.2202.688 and have come across a very strange issue.  When I hit the "Enter" key to add a line break from within a Script tag, ReSharper is automatically adding the line "foo foo".

```
<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD XHTML 1.0 Transitional//EN" "http://www.w3.org/TR/xhtml1/DTD/xhtml1-transitional.dtd">
<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml">
<head>
    <title></title>
    <script src="senchatouch.2/sencha-touch-all-debug.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
    <link href="senchatouch.2/resources/css/sencha-touch.css" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" />
</head>
<body>
<script type="text/javascript">

foo foo 
foo foo 
foo foo 
foo foo 
foo foo 
foo foo 
foo foo 
foo foo 

  });</script>

</body>
</html>
```

I tried to find this in the LiveTemplates but dont see any that would apply.

I did not see any ReSharper configuring that would cause this issue either. Also, it just randomly started happening as I was going through some Sencha Touch tutorials.

Any idea what would cause this?
Thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Please install the latest [ReSharper 6.1.1](http://www.jetbrains.com/resharper/download/index.html)
This bug was fixed since the release of version 6.0 that you're currently using.

Comment: Oh, so its a known issue.  Guess I will need to upgrade, then.  Thats an interesting bug.  Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

I also had this problem and upgraded to ReSharper 6.1.1. However, it didn't fix it. In fact, according to the YouTrack page for this bug, it wasn't fixed until version 7.0.43.13

http://youtrack.jetbrains.com/issue/RSRP-291030

Answer (score 0):

It was happening to me in 7.0.1 (7.0.1098.2760)

I've found the fault to be within a malformed script block whereby a server-side script block was embedded inside a client-side one. e.g.

```
<script type="text/javascript" language="javascript">
    <script runat="server" language="C#">
        string ServerString = "this breaks things";
    </script>
    var clientString="<%=ServerString() %>";
</script>

<script type="text/javascript" language="javascript">
// try typing something here and hitting enter for "foo"
</script>
```

The fix for me was to move the nested server side script block outside of the client side script block.

Note: Blame removal - this wasn't my code!  I was getting random foo inserted into my code and wanted it to stop!

I've opened a new support ticket with JetBrains as it seems odd to want to insert "foo" and delete other characters from source, even if I have malformed html/script.